# Get array of friend names with friend id's from MongoDB

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, angular, express

I'm making MEAN app for the first time. I managed to insert users into MongoDB. Each user looks like:

```
{
"name":"My Name",
"country":"Italy",
"friends":"5922c66b4e708e27a02b7937"
}
```

My first question is, how to manualy insert more than one friend (how to separate them via Postman)?

Then I have html page to show those informations about user, so I display his friends that way:

```
<td>{{user.userFriends}}</td>
```

When I will have more than one firend in database, how to display number of friends instead of their IDs?

Thanks for help!

EDIT: Solved the first part with

```
{
"friends":["5922c66b4e708e27a02b7937","5922c66b4e708e27a02b7938"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Mongo to calculate the number of friends a user has, you can use the `$size` operator on the `friends` array. You need to use the aggregation pipeline to do this though. Otherwise, you can just calculate the length of the array yourself. For more details on the `$size` operator and the aggregation pipeline, see here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/

Comment: I'm adding users manualy via postman just for now. Later that will be done via registration form. On the main page I want to display only number of friends each user have, and than later on profile I would like to display IDs(names) of those users.

Comment: What I mentioned will allow you to get the number of friends each user has. As for how you want to display it, that's up to you. And as for getting the name of each user from the friends array, you will either need to change the structure of each element in the array to include the name (so instead of just adding IDs to the array add an object with id and name properties), or do a separate query to get the names associated with those IDs :)